# Looping Through a Bitmap Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, bitmap

```
Dim bmpNew As Bitmap = Nothing
Dim Bitmaps(15) As Bitmap

For b = 0 To Bitmaps.Count - 1
    If Bitmaps.Contains(bmpNew) Then
    Else
        If Bitmaps(b) Is Nothing Then
            If Bitmaps(b) Is bmpNew Then
            Else
                Bitmaps(b) = bmpNew
            End If
        Else
        End If
    End If
    ListBox1.Items.Add(b)
Next
```

I am developing an application that generates random images every time the button is pressed. After generating the image, it loops through an array of bitmaps which are initially empty. What it should do is fill the array with every new image that it creates while making sure to not add it if it already exists in the array. I have tried many attempts and this method is the only one that actually makes sense and is very close to what I am trying to achieve, but it still produces duplicates in my array.

What am I missing?

Comment: How could the array already contain a `Bitmap` that you just created?  It couldn't.  Even if you create two `Bitmaps` that contain exactly the same data, they are still not the same `Bitmap`.  How are you creating the `Bitmaps` in the first place?  Why are you creating one if it will contain the same data as one you already have?

Comment: A Bitmap is a reference type. If you create a new Bitmap, it won't be *Equal* to another one, no matter what it contains. You could hash it and compare the hash (no guarantees either, if the Bitmap is then converted to a JPEG image, for example). Or make sure not to generate identical images in the first place.

Comment: I am setting each pixel in the bitmap to one of 2 colors that are in a color array based on their index number and I am obtaining that chosen color's index number by a random. I am looping through each pixel on the bitmap and setting it to the chosen color. Then I am putting that bitmap in the bitmap array if the bitmap array does not contain it already.

Comment: So instead of checking if the bitmap array contains the bitmap, I should be comparing the bitmap to each bitmap in the array?
```if bmpnew is bitmaps(b)``` I actually did that too though.

Comment: No, because that's the exact same thing.  What you would need to do is compare every pixel in the new `Bitmap` to every pixel in every existing `Bitmap`, which is not practical.  The best solution would be to create a hash for each `Bitmap` and then you can simply compare hashes, which will be all but instantaneous.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I have never dabbled with hashes but I will research it and see if that works. Thanks. So should I store these hashes in another array?

Comment: each image created will have a new hash so even the duplicates will have different hashes so I don't think that will work either. Back to the drawing board.. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you hash the same data then you get the same hash.  Two `Bitmaps` created from the same data will produce the same hash.  NOT back to the drawing board.  You don't even need to hash the `Bitmap` data itself, but just the data used to generate them.  You say that you're using two colours so you can create a hash based on one byte per pixel.  You just have to think the problem through.

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/531261837283557376/629261021424386048/unknown.png
in this screenshot, i tested it. the images 1 and 4 are the same image. the hashes in the second listbox of items 1 and 4 are different.